# Like page Facebook with cURL with Asp.net MVC

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, facebook, curl, page-curl

I have a php code which logs in facebook using cURL, but we need the same functionality in C # (ASP.NET MVC), since I've been reading the documentation of cURL and C # have similar classes, such as HttpWebRequest, the problem I am finding at the moment is what information to pass in order to run successfully in C #. 
For example in CURL believe "CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS 'is a const or # define, the problem is, as I POSTFIELDSa I refer to the name in HttpWebRequest? 
and if you have any documents (created by others perhaps) who speaks what should be the constants used in HttpWebRequest that is worth the cURL?

```
function likeFS($email, $senha, $idpost, $idUser) { //Like Foto & Status
    $cookie    = '../cookie/' . $email . '.txt';
    $datr      = substr(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "", base64_encode(md5(time()))), -24);
    $userAnget = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0';
    $ch        = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Host: www.facebook.com',
        'Accept-Language: pt-br',
        'Cookie: datr=' . $datr . ';'
    ));
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php?m&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fhome.php',
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "email=" . $email . "&pass=" . $senha . "&persistent=1",
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookie,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookie,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $userAnget
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if (strpos($response, 'checkpoint/?next') == true) {
        unset($response);
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the c# SDK library: http://facebooksdk.net/ It's also listed on FB's third party library page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/other-sdks